# Using Bootstrap 4.6.0 dynamic tabs not working properly, before upgrading with bootstrap 3.3.1 worked fine

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have upgraded bootstrap version from 3.3.1 to 4.6.0 in my existing project.
I found that for random tabs are not loading properly where I'm working with dynamic tabs using for loop.

I'm binding all tabs data using for loop when page loading itself, some tabs are working fine but some tabs are not working.

static tabs are always are working fine, but only few dynamic tabs (randomly) not loading.

Please help me...

```
<div id="divRiskLOBs" class="width100p">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    @if (Model.RiskLOBList != null)
                    {
                        int i = 0;
                        foreach (var item in Model.RiskLOBList.Where(x => x.Parent_ID == null))
                        {
                            
                            string activeClass = "";
                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.RiskCoverageTabID) && item.LOB_ID_EN == Model.RiskCoverageTabID)
                            {
                                activeClass = "active";
                            }
                            else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.RiskCoverageTabID) && i == 0)
                            {
                                activeClass = "active";
                            }
                            <li class="@activeClass">
                                <a href="#@item.LOB_ID_EN" class="aTab" data-toggle="tab" data-id="@item.LOB_ID_EN">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            i++;
                        }
                        <li><a href="#tabExceptions" class="aTab" data-toggle="tab" data-id="" id="aExceptions1"><strong>Exceptions</strong></a></li>
                    }
                    <li id="liActivity"><a href="#tabActivity" class="aTab" data-toggle="tab" data-id="" id="aRequestActivity"><strong>Activity</strong></a></li>

                    <li id="liDocuments"><a href="#tabDocuments" class="aTab" data-toggle="tab" data-id="" id="aDocuments"><strong>Documents</strong></a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
```

---

```
                <div class="tab-content mb30">
                @if (Model.RiskLOBList != null)
                {
                    int iLOBIndex = 1;
                    int j = 0;
                    foreach (var item in Model.RiskLOBList.Where(x => x.Parent_ID == null))
                    {

                        string activeClass = "";
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.RiskCoverageTabID) && item.LOB_ID_EN == Model.RiskCoverageTabID)
                        {
                            activeClass = "active";
                        }
                        else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.RiskCoverageTabID) && j == 0)
                        {
                            activeClass = "active";
                        }


                        <div class="tab-pane @activeClass" id="@item.LOB_ID_EN">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8 align-right mb10 divRiskActionButton">
                               ///my code
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        j++;
                    }

                    <div class="tab-pane row" id="tabExceptions">
                           //my code
                    </div>
                }

                <div class="tab-pane" id="tabActivity">
                    //my code
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tabDocuments">
                    //my code
                </div>

            </div>
```

---

here is my tab active code which is need to be added, if we use bootstrap 4.6.0

```
 $(document).on("click", ".nav-tabs li a", function (e) {
        $(".nav-tabs li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    });
```